# EpoxyRecyclerView inside of ViewPager

Tags: android, epoxy

Using EpoxyRecyclerView inside of ViewPager

```
@Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup collection, int position) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);

            ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(idLists.get(position), collection, false);
            collection.addView(layout);

            splitRecyclerView = (EpoxyRecyclerView) layout.findViewById(R.id.split_recycler_view);

            splitRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this.mContext));

            splitRecyclerView.setController(controller);

            updateController(position);

            return layout;
        }
```

Error:

> 09-03 22:54:36.394 23354-23354/com.milcgroup.one E/AndroidRuntime:
>   FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>           Process: com.milcgroup.one, PID: 23354
>           java.lang.IllegalStateException: This EpoxyController had its adapter added to more than one ReyclerView. Epoxy does not support
>   attaching an adapter to multiple RecyclerViews because saved state
>   will not work properly. If you did not intend to attach your adapter
>   to multiple RecyclerViews you may be leaking a reference to a previous
>   RecyclerView. Make sure to remove the adapter from any previous
>   RecyclerViews (eg if the adapter is reused in a Fragment across
>   multiple onCreateView/onDestroyView cycles). See
>   https://github.com/airbnb/epoxy/wiki/Avoiding-Memory-Leaks for more
>   information.
>               at com.airbnb.epoxy.EpoxyController$3.run(EpoxyController.java:690)
>               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>               at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)

Comment: Differentiate error from code block. Proper code formatting

Comment: please check if you used the adapter somewhere else, if not please provide more code snipped